# how communicate two separate .vue files?

Tags: javascript, events, vue.js

In a project with vue.js 2:

I've a component living in a .vue file that represents a list of elements. Also, I've a sidebar that is the summary of this list. This sidebar is another component in a .vue file. 
So, how I can keep communication between each them, for example, if I removed a element from a list, reflect the change in a var declared in sidebar that is the total number of elements?To ilustrate:
 
*SideBar.vue*

```
<template>
    ...
    <span></span> ===> here I need total of elements listed in ListElements.vue
    ...
<template>
```

*ListElements.vue*

```
<template>
    ...
    @click="deleteEntry"
    ...
<template>

<script>
    methods: {
      deleteEntry(entry) {
        //here I need to notify to SideBar.vue in order to update the total of elements in the this.entries list.
        let index = this.entries.indexOf(entry);
        if (window.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this time entry?'))            {
          this.entries.splice(index, 1);
        }
      }
</script>
```

Comment: Can you please add some code (simplified if possible)  to show the problem?

Comment: This may be helpful: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication

Comment: I've read this already, but I don't know how to keep the same instance of the bus object across two components in two separates .vue file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I've created a simplified example of how this works. Your bus needs to be global so it is accessible by all `Vue` components, this simply means placing it outside of all other components and view models:

```
var bus = new Vue({});

var vm = new Vue({
   // Main view model has access to bus
   el: '#app'
});
```

Then you just need to emit the event on the bus on some event and catch that in the other component:

Component one emits a message to the bus on keyup:

```
Vue.component('component-one', {
  template: '<div>Enter a message: <input v-model="msg" v-on:keyup="updateMessage"> </div>',
  methods: {
    updateMessage() {
       bus.$emit('msg', this.msg);
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      msg: ""
    }
  }
});
```

Component-two listens for the message:

```
Vue.component('component-two', {
  template: "<div><b>Component one says: {{ msg }}</b></div>",
  created() {
    bus.$on('msg', (msg) => {
      this.msg = msg;
    });
  },
  data() {
    return {
      msg: ""
    }
  }
});
```

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v7o6d2vL/

For your single page components to get access the the bus you just need to make sure your bus is in the global scope, which you can do by using `window`:

```
window.bus = new Vue({});
```

you can then use `bus.$emit()` and `bus.$on()` inside your components as normal

Comment: all this components are in the same file, how I can share the bus instance across multiples .vue files?

Comment: Thanks, thats a really nice example, exactly what I needed!